# how can Apache reverse proxy to aspnet core api and anular 6 application

Tags: angular, apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I have an `aspnet core api` running on `localhost:8080` (kestrel). Everything works perfectly on `localhost:80` (apache reverse proxy) which is accessible from internet on `www.example.com`

I want to deploy the angular client on this port `locahost:80`(`www.example.com`) and still be able to access the api on `www.api.example.com` and `www.example.com/api`. How to modify my virtual host in my `.conf` file?

```
 <VirtualHost *:*>
     RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" http
     RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" https
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias *.example.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/core_log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/core_access_log common
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/
```